# Does a python iterator really have to be an iterable?

Tags: python, iterator

I have always found it horribly confusing that python [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) are required to be [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable),
since it seems to me that attempting to iterate over an iterator is,
logically, a type mismatch.  Is there a reason for this requirement?

The explanation, according to the [definition of iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), is:

> Iterators are required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the
> iterator object itself so every iterator is also iterable and may be
> used in most places where other iterables are accepted.

But that doesn't explain it: *why* is advantageous for an iterator to be
"used in most places that accept iterables"?  As far as I can see, this only adds unnecessary confusion,
since, as far as I am aware, I don't *want* my iterators to be used in places where iterables are accepted.

That is, you say this:

```
for item in myContainer:
```

never this, in my experience:

```
for item in myIterator:
```

So, when I define an iterator class, my inclination is to simply ignore
that strange requirement; that is, I am inclined to define `__next__()` as usual,
but refrain from defining `__iter__()`.
Such "iterators" still seem to work perfectly fine,
and are less confusing and less error prone (more typesafe)
than they would be if I followed the requirement.

Will any harm come to me, my program, or my users if I do this?  That is:

- will my "iterators" fail to be useful in some way?
- might they stop working as intended, in a future version of python?

Further, I wonder if there is a chance that this strange requirement
might simply be removed in some future version of the python documentation, without harm.

I see that there is already a somewhat-mysterious note in the above-linked doc, shortly after the above-quoted section:

> CPython implementation detail: CPython does not consistently apply
> the requirement that an iterator define `__iter__()`.

That's interesting information, but I'm not sure what to conclude from it, in terms of guidance.  It seems to me that one possible interpretation is "you may not need to make your iterators be iterables after all".
And an opposing possible interpretation is "beware: if you make an iterator that isn't an iterable, it may appear to work in some or most cases, but then it may unexpectedly fail to work in some situations or future versions of CPython".  A third possible interpretation is something like "we acknowledge that this is a strange requirement, and no one has a clear idea of what we're doing with it or whether/where it should be enforced".

Comment: Why do you define an iterator if you don't want to it to be iterable?

Comment: If your iterator doesn't define `__iter__` then you can still use it as an argument to `next(myiter)`, but it wouldn't work in situations like `list(myiter)` or `for x in myiter:` that are written to work for iterables.

Comment: @Barmar iterables (e.g. ranges, lists and other containers) and their iterators are conceptually two different things.   When you iterate over an iterable, the iterator is the object holding the current state/position in the iteration.  So when I define an iterator, that's what it's for; there's no reason for it to be an iterable itself.

Comment: @rhelwood.  Right.  Are you saying `list(myIter)` or `for x in myIter:` is useful?  Have you ever typed such a thing?

Comment: I think `__iter__()` is used if you call `iter(myIter)`

Comment: @Barmar Right, `__iter__()` is called if you call `iter(myIter)`.  Why would you do that?

Comment: So you can do `for i in iter(myIter):`. Again, why define an iterator if you don't want to iterate over it like that?

Comment: @Barmar I'm asking why would you want `for i in myIter` since that doesn't seem useful to me, let alone `for i in iter(myIter)` or `for i in iter(iter(myIter))` etc. which seem increasingly non-useful.  The usual use of an iterator I write is to iterate over a container I have written.  That looks like `for x in myContainer`, which calls `iter(myContainer)` under the hood, which in turn returns my iterator, and then next() is called on my iterator.  iter() never gets called on the iterator itself, during any of that.

Comment: @DonHatch: I want to iterate over all but the first element of the container. I write `it = iter(myContainer)`, then `next(it, None)` (to throw away the first element), then `for x in it:`. Oops, the code exploded. Just write the identity function for `__iter__`, it takes no work. Or more commonly, don't even write an iterator class at all, just implement `__iter__` on the container as a generator function and save yourself a ton of boilerplate (not to mention typically getting faster code).

Comment: The question is, should an iterator be iterable? Should you be able to iterate over it, like you can iterate over a container? Should an iterator over a given container be substitutable for the container itself? I think that is obvious...

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you, yes, your first example is the first legitimate use case anyone has pointed out.  However, I don't recall ever having typed that (or similar) in a program, have you?  I'm not saying uncommon use cases can't be important, but it doesn't feel to me like this particular one justifies the requirement in question and all the resultant fallout from it (confusion and type unsafety).  If I ever run into that use case, I don't think I would feel too put-out by having to code it up a different way.

Comment: @ShadowRanger regarding your second use case ("Or more commonly"), I don't see this as a valid argument for requiring all iterators to be iterables.  You could certainly do the optimization you describe (at the expense of some type safety and clarity) even if there was no such requirement.

Comment: @DonHatch: I've used it before (not with custom collections, but with file-like objects for instance, to throw away a header line). Similarly, a common recipe to iterate over fixed sized chunks of items from an iterator (e.g. to iterate three elements at a time, with filler elements for the final chunk if it's not an even multiple of the chunk size) is `for x, y, z in itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(collection)]*3):`. You preconvert to an iterator, pass three aliases of the same iterator to `zip_longest`, and it pulls three elements at a time on your behalf.

Comment: `zip_longest` itself calls `iter()` on all its arguments, so that idiom fails if your iterators don't define `__iter__`. And of course, an approach to trigger a check for iterability before you're ready to iterate (e.g. because you need to be sure it's iterable before you perform some hard to undo thing) is to do `it = iter(argument)`, then later iterate over `it`, and when you do so, it's going to implicitly call `iter` again, and boom.

Comment: @DonHatch: To be clear, my "Or more commonly" was not an argument that way. It was an argument for almost never actually writing an iterator class at the Python level (with or without `__iter__`); there's rarely any reason to do it, and it's inherently less efficient than implementing the iterable's `__iter__` as a generator function. The argument for always implementing the identity `__iter__` function is because Python's spec requires it, and the assumption that calling `iter` unconditionally on iterables of any stripe is so baked in that you'll eventually get burned if you don't do it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the real examples, I like the 3-items-at-a-time trick.  The various insights you've given above might go well in an answer.